# How do I set up my Dockerfile to use cpanm to install a specific version of a Perl module?

Tags: perl, docker, dockerfile, cpanm

Within my Dockerfile, I am setting up the Perl modules that will be installed when run, like so:

`RUN ["cpanm", "Carp", "Carp::Heavy", "Class::Data::Inheritable"]`

However, for one module, I need a specific version of a module, not the latest one.  How can I specify that version in the above line?

I've been searching online for hours, and haven't turned up anything useful yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of specifying a module name, specify a URL. Eg, instead of `Class::Data::Inheritable`, use `https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/T/TM/TMTM/Class-Data-Inheritable-0.06.tar.gz`

You can find the applicable URL by going to the [module page on metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Data::Inheritable), selecting the version you want, and copying the download link.

PS: You might want to also set `PERL_CPANM_OPT=--from https://cpan.metacpan.org/` in the environment so `cpanm` only downloads using `HTTPS`.

Comment: Great tip about the environment option!

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who's searching for this same answer in the future, another option can be found here in [the documentation for `cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm):

> ```
> cpanm Plack@0.9990
> ```

If you have a long list of modules, consider feeding a [`cpanfile`](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanfile) into `cpanm` rather than listing them all in the Dockerfile.

The easiest way to specify a particular version number for a module in a `cpanfile` is like this:

```
requires 'Text::ParseWords', '==3.1';
```

The syntax for requesting the latest version of a module is this:

```
requires 'Text::ParseWords';
```

Requesting a minimum version: (note the lack of '==')

```
requires 'Text::ParseWords', '3.1';
```

The syntax for requesting specific versions in other ways is fairly well-documented [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanfile).

Another great write-up of the use of `cpanm` and a `cpanfile` can be found 
in [Installation of cpan modules by cpanm and cpanfile](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Installation-of-cpan-modules-by-cpanm-and-cpanfile).

Comment: Excellent summary (I am going to tidy up the formatting a little later). However, note that, in production, I like to know exactly where everything is coming from. For that purpose, you may want to keep your own repository of specific instances of CPAN dist files. See also [CPAN::Mini](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Mini) and [Pinto](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pinto).

Comment: Thanks.  I looked into Pinto and decided that it would be overkill, since I'm just using this to spin up Docker containers.  [Carton](https://metacpan.org/release/carton) is another tool to consider, though it also uses the cpanfile, and I'm having trouble digging up working syntax to include a url instead of a version number in the cpanfile.

Comment: I don't think there is syntax for including modules by URL in a cpanfile. However, you can probably achieve the same effect by setting the mirror in the environment, and specifying an exact version.

Comment: I did find this **one** blog post with syntax for including a git url.  Sadly, the line is cut off.  I've made a couple of guesses, but so far cpanm keeps trying to translate the url into a version number:  http://blogs.perl.org/users/lestrrat/2013/03/the-main-problem-with-cpan-modules-on-github.html

Comment: Looking at the source of the web page, it seems to be `requires 'My::Experimental::Module" => "git://github.com/lestrrat/p5-MyExperimental-Module.git";`

Comment: LOL, can't believe I didn't think to look at the source.  I guess that's what happens when you stare at the same problem for too long.  However, that is one of the syntax variations that I tried, and cpanm interpreted it as a version number, regardless of the "=>" between.  I left a comment on the blog post requesting clarification regarding the syntax, so hopefully the blogger can provide some missing context or clarification.  Thanks for all the effort you've put into this; it's been extremely helpful.

Comment: The reason I had not originally suggested something like that was because I looked at the source of the cpanfile module to see if requirements options checked for URLs and I could not find a check, I assumed it did not exist. The blog post made me think I had missed something. I should have tried. Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 4):

To have CPAN install a specific version of a module, you need to provide the full module distribution filename including the author. For example to install the module `Set::Object` version `1.28`, at the command line type:

```
cpan SAMV/Set-Object-1.28.tar.gz
```

Same thing apply with Docker, just add

```
RUN cpan SAMV/Set-Object-1.28.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify target module version you can use

```
cpanm MIYAGAWA/Plack-0.99_05.tar.gz              # full distribution path
cpanm http://example.org/LDS/CGI.pm-3.20.tar.gz  # install from URL
cpanm ~/dists/MyCompany-Enterprise-1.00.tar.gz   # install from a local file
```

See official documentation: https://metacpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/view/bin/cpanm

But better, to my mind, would be to use `cpanfile`. See `--cpanfile` option https://metacpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/view/bin/cpanm#-cpanfile and format of this file https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanfile

But if you have many modules (like me), I recommend to use `cpm`. It installs modules in parallel very fast. Also with help of docker we could cache builds, thus rebuilds will takes seconds. Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
## Modules
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}

# install modules outside of WORKDIR, so it will not interfere when we do COPY . .
RUN  mkdir -p ../modules
RUN  ln -s ../modules local

RUN  cpanm -n -L ./local App::cpm Carton::Snapshot  && rm -rf /root/.cpanm
COPY cpanfile ./
COPY cpanfile.snapshot ./
RUN  \
  --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.perl-cpm   \
  cpm install  -w 16  --no-test  -L ./local   \
  --with-develop


# regenerate cpanfile.snapshot
# https://github.com/miyagawa/Carmel#cpm
# cpm doesn't have the ability to manage cpanfile.snapshot file on its own.
RUN  carton install
# You can copy snapshot from container by running:
# docker cp <container_name>:${APP_ROOT}/cpanfile.snapshot.latest ./cpanfile.snapshot
```